# Shift/reduce conflict in Happy grammar

Tags: haskell, grammar, parser-generator, happy, ambiguous-grammar

I've got the following (heavily stripped down) Happy grammar

```
%token
   '{'   { Langle }
   '}'   { Rangle }
   '..'  { DotDot }
   '::'  { ColonColon }
   '@'   { At }
   mut   { Mut }
   ident { Ident }

 %%

 pattern
   : binding_mode ident at_pat  { error "identifier pattern" }
   | expr_path                  { error "constant expression" }
   | expr_path '{' '..' '}'     { error "struct pattern" }

 binding_mode
   : mut                        { }
   |                            { }

 at_pat
   : '@' pat                    { }
   |                            { }

 expr_path
   : expr_path '::' ident       { }
   | ident                      { }
```

Which has shift/reduce conflicts around identifiers in patterns. By default, Happy chooses to shift, but in this case that isn't what I want: it tries to shoe-horn everything into `constant expression` even when it could be an `identifier pattern`.

I've read that precedence/associativity is the way to solve this sort of problem, but nothing I've added has been able to budge the grammar in the right direction (to be fair, I've been taking mostly shots in the dark).

Using some obvious tokenization, I would like to have:

- `x` to yield `identifier pattern`
- `mut x` to yield `identifier pattern`
- `std::pi` to yield `constant expression`
- `point{..}` to yield `struct pattern`
- `std::point{..}` to yield `struct pattern`

Basically, unless there is a `{` or `::` token waiting to be consumed, an identifier should go to the `identifier pattern` case.

---

I apologize if my question is unclear - part of the problem is that I'm having a tough time pinpointing what the problem even is. :(

Comment: I think you missed some of the productions. As presented, there is no conflict (and no constant_expression)

Comment: @rici That may very well be the case. If so, I'll delete the question and review it more carefully before reposting! There is not supposed to be a `constant_expression` production - that is just the message I chose to print having encountered the `expr_path` variant of `pattern`. And I think there should be at least one shift/reduce conflict - given just an `Ident`, I can shift from `pattern` into the `expr_path` variant, or reduce `binding_mode ident at_pat` altogether.

Comment: Ok, it would have been clearer for me had you characterized the results as productions rather than actions; i tend to ignore actions. Is your intention that an unadorned identifier be a pattern? Why don't you just write the grammar to say that?

Comment: Yes, it was my intention that unadorned identifiers be patterns. I didn't write it as such because I wasn't convinced those other parts weren't part of the problem. Please feel free to edit the question to make it clearer - I don't pretend to have any real experience in writing grammars, let alone debugging them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it's important to understand what a shift is. A shift is the result of accepting the next input token, and putting it on the parser stack (where it will eventually be part of a production, but it is not necessary to know which one yet.) A reduction is taking zero or more tokens off the top of the stack which match the right-hand side of some production, and replacing them with the left-hand side.

When the parser decides to create an `identifier pattern` out of `binding_mode ident at_pat` where `at_pat` is empty, it is not shifting; it is reducing. In fact, it reduces twice: first it reduces zero stacked symbols into an empty `at_pat` and then it reduces the top three stack symbols into an `identifier pattern`. Had there been no `binding_mode`, it could have reduced `ident` to `expr_path` and then reduced the `expr_path` into a `constant_expression`. So that would be a reduce/reduce conflict.

But there is another issue, precisely because `binding_mode` is nullable. When the parser sees an `ident`, it does not know whether or not a `binding_mode` would be possible, so it doesn't know whether to reduce an empty `binding_mode` or to shift the `ident`. That is a shift/reduce conflict. Since it prefers shift to reduce, it chooses to shift the `ident`, which means that an empty `binding_mode` cannot be produced , which in turn precludes the reduce/reduce conflict (and prevents `ident @ pat` from being recognized at all.)

So to untangle all of that, we need to start by avoiding the necessity to reduce an empty `binding_mode`. We do that by the usual nullable-production elimination algorithm, which involves making two copies of the right-hand side, one with the nullable nonterminal, and the other without; we then remove the nullable production. Once we do that, the reduce/reduce conflict appears.

To avoid the reduce/reduce conflict, we need to be explicit about which production is preferred. Reduce/reduce conflicts cannot be resolved through precedence declarations because the precedence algorithm always involves the comparison between a production (which could be reduced) and a terminal (which could be shifted). So the resolution must be explicit, and that means that we need to say that a bare `ident` is a pattern, while an `expr_path` which is not an `ident` is a constant expression. That leaves us with the following:

(Note that I've used non-terminals to label the three different productions for `pattern`, rather than relying on actions. For me that makes it easier to think about, and read.)

```
pattern: identifier_pattern | constant_expression | struct_pattern
```

Here is the null production elimination:

```
identifier_pattern:   ident at_pat 
                  |   binding_mode ident at_pat
```

Here is the explicit prohibition on idents:

```
constant_expression:  complex_expr_path 

struct_pattern:       expr_path '{' '..' '}'
```

`binding_mode` is no longer nullable:

```
binding_mode: mut

at_pat
   : '@' pat
   | %empty
```

Here we create the two different expr_paths:

```
complex_expr_path
   : complex_expr_path '::' ident
   | ident '::' ident

expr_path: ident | complex_expr_path
```

I hope that solution has some relationship to your original grammar.

Comment: Yeah. This is generally the idea I was going to try (the `complex_expr_path`). I think I can somehow make this work with my grammar. Thank you for such a detailed answer!